# I have a homework about using class and object

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

I do not know how to write code for the turn() to change the direction from left to right or vice versa. Please help! I just start learning C++.

[image: my .cpp file]

[![my .h file][2]][2]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code as text, not images.  For people that can't see images for one reason or another your question is unanswerable.

Comment: `turn` isn't the only issue. `move` is broken too. You need read the requirements closer, and think about them carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the position is changed in `move()`.

It is always increased by `1` so it will always move in one direction.

`direction` currently has no impact on `position`.

You should change `move()` to increase the `position` by the `direction`. This would look like `position += direction`.

Now `position` changes when the `direction` changes, but currently the `direction` changes based on the `position` and this should not be the case.

You should change `turn()` to invert the direction, so if it was `1` change it to `-1` and vice versa. Replacing the current definition with `direction = -direction` will do this.

---

### Update

Bug header file:

```cpp
#ifndef H27_H_
#define H27_H_

/** A bug climbing a pole. */
class Bug
{
public:
    Bug(int startPos);    // construct Bug at starting position
    void move();          // move bug one unit in direction
    void turn();          // Change the direction from left to right or vice-versa
    int position() const; // Return the position
private:
    int position_;
    int direction_;
};

#endif
```

Bug source file:

```cpp
#include "Bug.h"

Bug::Bug(int startPos)
{
    position_ = startPos;
    direction_ = 1;
}

void Bug::move()
{
    position_ += direction_;
}

void Bug::turn()
{
    direction_ = -direction_;
}

int Bug::position() const
{
    return position_;
}
```

Main testing file:

```cpp
#include "Bug.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Testing Bugs -------------------" << endl;
    // create bugs
    cout << "Constructing sam at position 2";
    Bug sam(2);
    cout << "->" << sam.position() << endl;
    cout << "Constructing julie at position 12";
    Bug julie(12);
    cout << "->" << julie.position() << endl;
    cout << "Constructing fred at position -10";
    Bug fred(-10);
    cout << "->" << fred.position() << endl;
    // move sam
    cout << "Moving sam one to the right";
    sam.move();
    cout << "->" << sam.position() << endl;
    cout << "Moving sam one more to the right";
    sam.move();
    cout << "->" << sam.position() << endl;
    // move fred
    cout << "Moving fred one to the left";
    fred.turn();
    fred.move();
    cout << "->" << fred.position() << endl;
    cout << "Moving fred one more to the left";
    fred.move();
    cout << "->" << fred.position() << endl;
    cout << "Moving fred back two places to the right";
    fred.turn();
    fred.move();
    fred.move();
    cout << "->" << fred.position() << endl;
}
```

Comment: I follow your advice. I got the right result when the bug moves to the left, but the wrong result when it moves to the right.

Comment: What is the wrong result that you are getting? And what is the right result that you are expecting? Is the bug not moving towards the right again?

Comment: Checking function: Testing Bugs -------------------
   + Constructing sam at position 2->2
   + Constructing julie at position 12->12
   + Constructing fred at position -10->-10
   + Moving sam one to the right.->3
   + Moving sam one more to the right.->4
   + Moving fred one to the left.->-11
   + Moving fred one more to the left.->-12
   X Moving fred back two places to the right.: expected "-10" but found "-14"

Comment: it moves to the left. However, it doesn't move to the right according to the test result (the last one).

Comment: I can not reproduce this. I will update my answer with the code I currently have that passes the test.

Comment: Check where your code differs from mine, and try find out what it is doing and why.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was putting an if in the turn(). If (direction_ ==1) -> direction_ = - direction.

Comment: No problem. So what your code was doing was only inverting the direction if the direction was facing right, so when the direction was facing left, it did not invert the direction again. If you were wanting to use if statements you could do `if (direction_ == 1) { direction_ = -1 } else { direction_ = 1 }` but I prefer using maths.